# Error -bash: ssh username@server -i: command not found

Tags: bash, ssh, terminal

I'm attempting to ssh into a server from terminal on MAC. It was working a few days ago but just stopped today.

When I enter `ssh username@server -i .ssh/file`

I get `-bash: ssh username@server -i: command not found`

`whereis ssh` yields /usr/bin/ssh

`echo $PATH` gives me a weird looking path
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin

I tried to set PATH to /usr/bin with `export PATH=/usr/bin` and it appears to set it but on restart it resets to the above path.

SSH Config when running `sudo nano /etc/ssh/ssh_config`

```
  GNU nano 2.0.6           File: /etc/ssh/ssh_config                            

#       $OpenBSD: ssh_config,v 1.34 2019/02/04 02:39:42 dtucker Exp $

# This is the ssh client system-wide configuration file.  See
# ssh_config(5) for more information.  This file provides defaults for
# users, and the values can be changed in per-user configuration files
# or on the command line.

# Configuration data is parsed as follows:
#  1. command line options
#  2. user-specific file
#  3. system-wide file
# Any configuration value is only changed the first time it is set.
# Thus, host-specific definitions should be at the beginning of the
# configuration file, and defaults at the end.

# Site-wide defaults for some commonly used options.  For a comprehensive
# list of available options, their meanings and defaults, please see the
# ssh_config(5) man page.
```

What finally worked for me is the following command:
`/usr/local/Cellar/openssh/8.6p1/bin/ssh username@server -i .ssh/file`

Comment: Are you sure there isn’t some incorrect quoting there? Basically the only way you could get the first message is by using `"ssh username@server -i" .ssh/file`.

Comment: I'm running command as shown without any quotes. Same with the last command that worked.

Comment: `-bash: ssh username@server -i: command not found` Somehow bash is interpreting the entire string "ssh username@server -i" as the name of the command to run. There are a couple of things that could cause this, but they mostly would involve you running the command in some other way than by just typing it in.

Comment: Did you paste the command? Or did you type it? If pasted, the chances are you copied from a source where (at least some) "spaces" are not regular ASCII spaces.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I typed in the command instead of pasting it in and it worked. I had no freakin clue. Thanks a million!